# VBA Excel ADODB query INSERT INTO Worksheet, getting error: The INSERT INTO statement contains following unknown fields

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

I'm trying to insert a row to an excel worksheet with ADODB.
I have a worksheet with predefined columns `(NAME, DATE, STATUS)`

The problem is that I'm not able to refer to the column name in the `INSERT STATEMENT`
As the code below, `INSERT INTO [LOG$]([NAME])` does not work. the error is:
`Insert Statement contains the following unknown field name: "NAME"`

but if I change from `NAME` to `F1`, it works as expected. 
My assumption is that it does not recognize the first row as the column name. So, I tried selecting the table and printing all the column names. But the engine could print the column names correctly.

I want to refer to the columns as its name, not F1, F2, .... 
How to fix it? thanks.

```
Sub add_to_log(ByVal name As String)

    Dim strconn As String
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    
    Dim strSQL As String, s As String
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim col As Variant
    
    'create connection
    strconn = "Data source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=NO"";"
    With conn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = strconn
        .Open
    End With
    
    'create query
    s = "INSERT INTO [LOG$]([NAME]) VALUES('" & name & "')"
    Debug.Print s
    
    'execute
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .CommandText = s
        .Execute
    End With
        

    conn.Close
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `strconn = "Data source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES"";`

Answer (score 0):

Well, 'name' is a reserved word. Here is a list of all reserved words.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/reserved-words